# batch file to find file if it is exist with perticular extension then copy and paste it in same folder with rename

Tags: windows, recursion

In my project I want add new resource file of local language. There are already some resource files in project which is distributed in many folders. Now I want such a batch file which is run in recursive for all sub folders for Finding a file which name like blabla.hi-IN.resx (eg: index.hi-IN.resx, home.hi-IN.resx etc) i.e file name which is contains 'hi-IN'. if it is exist in a folder then copy and paste it in same folder with rename blabla.mr-IN.resx (eg: index.mr-IN.resx, home.mr-IN.resx).

---

```
for-each(var folder in folders)
{
   if(Exist(*G.hi-IN.resx))
     {
       Copy();
       Paste();
       rename(name);
     }
}
   void rename(string name)
   {
      remove hi-IN;
      append mr-IN;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Task can be done using my small powershell script.

This fetches all files recursively ending with **hi-IN.resx**

```
$files = gci -Filter *hi-IN.resx -Recurse
```

This prepares a Regex-object, which allows to remove **hi-IN.resx** in file name.

```
$reg = [regex]::new("hi-IN.resx")
```

This iterates over all files found in step one. For every file a copy is performed. The destination file Name is prepared using Regex-object prepared in step 2.

```
$files | foreach { Copy-Item $_.FullName ($r.Replace($_.FullName,"")+"mr-IN.resx") }
```

This is the full script:

```
$files = gci -Filter *hi-IN.resx -Recurse
$reg = [regex]::new("hi-IN.resx")
$files | foreach { Copy-Item $_.FullName ($r.Replace($_.FullName,"")+"mr-IN.resx") }
```